# Force pages to load inside webview instead external browsers keeping a low API lvl

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

I´m trying to have all my urls loaded inside my webView in android studio instead in external browsers, I succed in this by implementing the following code:

```
 webview.apply{
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
settings.useWideViewPort = true
webViewClient = MyClient()
loadUrl("http://url.com")
 }


inner class MyClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: 
           WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(request?.url?.toString())
        return true
    }
```

(thanks to pistolcaffe for the code described above)

However, the "inner class MyClient:..." part, requires API level 21 at least, and and I really would love to achieve the same result without having to move my level from 17 to 21, since I really need my app to be able to be installed in lower versions of Android.

Is there a way to do it?

thank you in advance for your support

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        view.loadUrl(url)
        return true
}
```

It's deprecated method but it will work as you don't wish to change **minSdkVersion=21**